# How to add terminal tabulation tips in my terminal application

Tags: linux, terminal, tabs

I am writing a program which is running from terminal, and I want to add this well-known functionality of Linux terminal, that if I double tabulate I get some tips of possible words I want to type. I type different combination of this title, but I found nothing. If you know better search phrase please write me tools or keywords I can use to solve my problem

EDIT: look in the comments to this post for solution

Comment: I'd start reading about [Programmable Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion). If you have difficulties with that, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: thank you a lot, that is what i want to achive. I'll try this today. You rescue my fingers from total destruction

Comment: If it's possible, add your comment as answer so i can mark this question as [SOLVED]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get the *tips* in the shell (for the program arguments and not, as I first misunderstood, inside the program itself), `bash`'s [Programmable Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) can provide that.